# Android Studio: AltGr + B shortcut not working

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, keyboard-shortcuts, keymapping

I've recently migrated from Eclipse to Android Studio and I had several problems which i mostly solved. One, which I don't have any idea to do with is, that the opening bracket shortcut <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> is not doing anything.

I've tried to:

- In Settings change the Keymaps to Eclipse | **NO SUCCESS**
- Add the line `actionSystem.force.alt.gr=true` to *idea.preferences* | **ACCESS TO FILE
  DENIED**

Do you have any idea what to do in my case?

Comment: It **doesn't do anything** in Eclipse, as well! What would **you** expect this shortcut to do?

Comment: I've used this for all my programming years. Altgr and B for "{" and AltGr and N for "}". What shortcut do you use?

Comment: I forgot to mention... I use Windows, Maybe you use a different OS?

Comment: I also use Windows. I have a Czech keyboard. Don't you think that it could be the cause? But how i mentioned, the shortcut i use(d) works for me everywhere but not in Android Studio.

Comment: Sorry... it's `Shift + AltGr` + [ or ]

Comment: This still doesn't work for me

Comment: I found out the solution. Thanks for your effort ;) Check out the answer

Comment: Ad Access to file denied: Open the editor as administrator.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well after hours of research and not finding solution online I've decided to solve it by myself. The thing which solved this issue (and I thing a lot of other shortcut problems) was just: 
going to Settings -> Keymaps and hitting the "Find actions by shortcut" button on the top right. I've just pressed the shortcut (in my case <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> - which **THE SAME** shortcut as <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>) and found out, that this shortcut was assigned to the "Implementation" action. I just right clicked the "<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>" area and removed the shortcut. After this process everything works well.

I hope that more people will find the solution here!

Comment: Great find. I'm using Eclipse, and on a different keyboard map, so, I'd never find this one... ;)

Comment: Yeah, I'm still seriously thinking over the migration to Android Studio. After more than year working with Eclipse, it's pretty shocking for me to switch to AS, haha

Comment: After 5 years of Eclipse. I tried migrating to AS, but I immediately switched back.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I always used copy+paste for " { " and " [ ". This was already frustrating after two days of using android studio :)

Answer (score 2):

the simple solution is adding the following line to the

```
<Android Studio folder>\bin\idea.properties file:

actionSystem.force.alt.gr=true
```

I placed this setting in the first line of the file (maybe it's not necessary) and it works for me nicely.

Fun fact, it worked for me nicely by default with Android Studio, and then suddenly it isn't (maybe I accidently pressed a shortcut or something o.O). But this solved the problem.

Keep in mind that if you update Anddoid Studio, the update can (and usually will) overwrite the idea.properties file, so keep a copy of it and overwrite after update (or the better is just copy this line from the old to the new).

An IDE restart is required to take effect.